# How to update existing opportunity field value

Tags: apex, opportunity, custom-field, compile-error

I am trying to replace opportunity field value using apex class,

```
public class update_system {
    public static String saveData(){
        for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id,system__c FROM Opportunity where system__c = 'Test (A)' and StageName Not in ('Closed','Closed Won','Closed Lost') limit 10
]){
               if (opp.system__c == 'Test (A)' ){ 
                   opp.update_system__c = 'Test';
                   update opp;

               }    
        }
     }
}
```

but i am getting below error

> Error Error: Compile Error: Invalid field update_system__c for SObject Opportunity at line 6 column 20

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the `update_system__c` field in your SOQL

Are you firing this from a trigger a button?
Either way, you should realize that you are just targeting one record at the time and giving a `LIMIT 10`?

You probably want to do something like this:

```
public class update_system {

    public static String saveData()
    {
     for (List<Opportunity> oppList : [SELECT Id,system__c FROM Opportunity where system__c = 'Test (A)' and StageName Not in ('Closed','Closed Won','Closed Lost') limit 10])
     {
         for(Opportunity opp: oppList)
         {
           if (opp.system__c == 'Test (A)') 
               opp.system__c = 'Test';
         } 
          update oppList;
     }

}
```

Assuming the field you want to update is `System__c` and not `Update_system__c`.

**You can just run this code in you developer console as anonymous block:**

```
for (List<Opportunity> oppList : [SELECT Id,system__c FROM Opportunity where system__c = 'Test (A)' and StageName Not in ('Closed','Closed Won','Closed Lost') limit 10])
{
 for(Opportunity opp: oppList)
  {
   if (opp.system__c == 'Test (A)') 
       opp.system__c = 'Test';
  } 
  update oppList;
}
```

But remember that all executions on anonymous code from your developer console will actually run in your org and make the changes, so please, make sure you are not executing this on production.

You can check this structure on this code coming from SFDC's documentation:

```
public void massUpdate() {
    for (List<Contact> contacts:
      [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact]) {
        for(Contact c : contacts) {
            if (c.FirstName == 'Barbara' &&
              c.LastName == 'Gordon') {
                c.LastName = 'Wayne';
            }
        }
        update contacts;
    }
}
```

Here the URL on '[Working with Very Large SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm)'.

Comment: How would that fix this compile error, which indicates `update_system__c` is not an existing field?

Comment: Yeah, probably the field is `System__c ` and not `update_system__c`

Comment: the field is system__C

Comment: after using Carlos Naranjo code im  getting below error
Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: opp at line 15 column 18

Comment: Yes, sorry, change `update opp` to `update oppList`. That should do it.

Comment: So you still have DML in a loop...

Comment: @Adrian, if you take a look at 'Working with Very Large SOQL Queries'  from SFDC's documentation, you will see that this is totally fine and it is actually very efficient when working with large records coming from an SOQL. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the field you are trying to set is called `System__c`, not `Update_System__c`. The API Name doesn't change due to context. It is constant. Also not you have DML in a loop, which violates Trigger Bulkification 101. Also note that your `if` condition is redundant, since you have already filtered `System__c = 'Test (A)'` in your query.

Here is what your code *should* look like:

```
public static String saveData()
{
    List<Opportunity> records = [
        SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE System__c = 'Test (A)'
        AND StageName NOT IN ('Closed', 'Closed Won', 'Closed Lost')
    ];
    for (Opportunity record : records)
    {
        record.System__c = 'Test';
    }
    update records;
}
```